# PL/SQL select from a table between 2 dates using variables

Tags: oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to select from a table using in the where clause 2 vaiables to filter records between date ranges; the two variables have the following values:

```
START DATE: 31-MAR-2019 00:00:00 and END DATE: 17-FEB-2020 05:00:00
```

however, if I use the variables in the where clause as

```
value_dtime BETWEEN TO_DATE(Start_Date) AND TO_DATE(End_Date);
```

I get a wrong dataset, whereas if I change the where clause as follow

```
value_dtime BETWEEN TO_DATE('31-MAR-2019 00:00:00') AND TO_DATE('17-FEB-2020 05:00:00');
```

I get the correct dataset; below the query i am using.

```
DECLARE
Start_Date VARCHAR(20):='31-MAR-2019 00:00:00';
End_Date VARCHAR(20):= TO_CHAR(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY') || ' 05:00:00' ; 

BEGIN

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('START DATE: ' || Start_Date || ' and END DATE: ' || End_Date); 

delete from inputs;

INSERT INTO inputs(dataset_id,asset_id,asset_name,value_numeric,added_by,value_date) 
SELECT 
   1,                   --value from LOOK_DATASETS table
  v.meas_ass_id ,   
   a.meas_id ,
  v.numeric_value ,
   v.mod_user,
   v.value_dtime  

FROM
   halo.t_meas_value@LNKHALO v
    JOIN halo.t_meas_ass@LNKHALO a ON a.ass_id = v.meas_ass_id
   WHERE   
     value_dtime BETWEEN TO_DATE(Start_Date) AND TO_DATE(End_Date);
END:
```

can someone please tell me how to get my correct dataset using the 2 variables and not hard coded date strings?

I am using an oracle 12C databae and SQL developer 19 as IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `VALUE_DTIME` column is `DATE` datatpye, then you should work with dates, not with strings (i.e. `varchar2` values). I'd suggest you to do it as follows:

- use date literal is always in `DATE 'YYYY-MM-DD'` format
- truncating sysdate sets date to today's midnight; adding 5/24 adds 5 hours so it is "today at 05:00 in the morning"
- `where` clause is then `WHERE value_dtime BETWEEN l_start_date AND l_end_date`

  - it is usually a good idea to use prefix for locally declared variables, such as `l_` or `v_` because it more than often happens that people use the same name for columns and variables (or parameters) which causes confusion and errors

If `VALUE_DTIME` is a string, then you'll hit another problems if values stored within aren't uniform and/or have valid date format.

OK, here you go:

```
DECLARE
   l_start_date  DATE := DATE '2019-03-31';
   l_end_date    DATE := TRUNC (SYSDATE) + 5 / 24;
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
      'START DATE: ' || start_date || ' and END DATE: ' || end_date);

   DELETE FROM inputs;

   INSERT INTO inputs (dataset_id,
                       asset_id,
                       asset_name,
                       value_numeric,
                       added_by,
                       value_date)
      SELECT 1,                               --value from LOOK_DATASETS table
             v.meas_ass_id,
             a.meas_id,
             v.numeric_value,
             v.mod_user,
             v.value_dtime
        FROM halo.t_meas_value@lnkhalo v
             JOIN halo.t_meas_ass@lnkhalo a ON a.ass_id = v.meas_ass_id
       WHERE value_dtime BETWEEN l_start_date AND l_end_date;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your code suggestion and for your solution which of course works perfectly. If I wanted to add 05:30:00 to the l_end_date (so hours and minutes) what would be the correct syntax?

Comment: You're welcome. You'd add `trunc(sysdate) + 5/24 + 30/(24 * 60)` because day has 24 hours (that's for 5/24), while hour has 60 minutes (that's for 30 / (24 * 60)).